# ExpressionEngine access to entry_date field in custom module

Tags: field, expressionengine

I am developing my custom module which needs to access the "entry_date" fields in the "channel_titles" table of my expressionengine database. I can print out the ee->TMPL object using print_r(); function and I can see my specific element which is "entry_date" but I don't know how can I access this field.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're looking in the template object. Just do an SQL query in your module using the URL title or entry ID then you have all the info you need right there.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot for your reply JamesNZ , 
I found out how to do it , I just run a query and fetch the data I needed , then
print it out on the template using $this->EE->TMPL->parse_variables($tagdata,$yourvariable); function , this work'd for me.